# MySQL count distinct query

Tags: mysql, select, distinct-values

I have a table which i kept kept posts comment_type, amount etc.

```
PostExtras
- id
- amount
- post_id (foreign key)
- comment_type (foreign key)
- ...

comment_type
- id
- name
```

I want to select posts which have duplicates comment-type.

Example:

```
- id     - amount    - post_id    - comment_type
 1         20          23           1
 2         45          23           2
 3         80          28           1
 4         78          28           2
 5         56          23           1
```

row 1 and 5 is actually same.

Comment: So you mean opposite of distinct?

Comment: i mean the posts which have two or more same comment_type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT post_id FROM PostExtras
GROUP BY post_id, comment_type
HAVING COUNT(comment_type) > 1
```

Comment: id is auto incremented. it does not have a meaning except indexing.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, use [COUNT, GROUP BY and HAVING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS itemcount FROM PostExtras 
GROUP BY post_id, comment_type
HAVING itemcount >= 2
```

Comment: This will not work due to all of the fields not being added to the grouping. You also cannot group by anything but post_id, comment_type  as there appear to be different values for each of the other columns, which will then return incorrect data.

Comment: I've added the WHERE clause for post_id, but about your other concern - you don't have to add all the fields to a GROUP BY clause in MySQL.

Comment: Although I am unable to confirm at this time, it seems strange that you can add the additional fields without grouping them. Also adding the where clause (indicating a selection of a single row) will almost certainly break this.

Comment: based on the above data and removing the where clause results in 2 rows being returned, which is what I would expect from the query above, but is not correct. Amending your SQL to; SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS itemcount FROM PostExtras  GROUP BY post_id, comment_type HAVING itemcount >= 2; will work. However, you are still returning unnecessary information as all that is required is the post_id.

Comment: Yes, that is incorrect, I might have misread the question and I've updated the answer. However, he wanted to select "posts which have duplicates comment-type.", not only post_ids.

Comment: I am going to assume by the fact the post_id is a foreign key, linked to the post itself that all the is required to get the 'posts which have duplicates comment-type' is in fact the post_id. The other information contained within this PostExtras table is additional information and not the 'post' itself. There will be a 1 to Many relationship between Posts and PostExtras in my opinion. Perhaps clarication from the OP is required on that.

Comment: I am assuming that he wants an answer to his question as it is.